# 'R', 'mice', missing variable imputation - how to only do one column in sparse matrix

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I have a matrix that is half-sparse.  Half of all cells are blank (na) so when I try to run the 'mice' it tries to work on all of them.  I'm only interested in a subset.

Question: In the following code, how do I make "mice" only operate on the first two columns?  Is there a clean way to do this using row-lag or row-lead, so that the content of the previous row can help patch holes in the current row?

```
set.seed(1)

#domain
x <- seq(from=0,to=10,length.out=1000)

#ranges
y <- sin(x) +sin(x/2) + rnorm(n = length(x))
y2 <- sin(x) +sin(x/2) + rnorm(n = length(x))

#kill 50% of cells
idx_na1 <- sample(x=1:length(x),size = length(x)/2)
y[idx_na1] <- NA

#kill more cells
idx_na2 <- sample(x=1:length(x),size = length(x)/2)
y2[idx_na2] <- NA

#assemble base data
my_data <- data.frame(x,y,y2)

#make the rest of the data
for (i in 3:50){


     my_data[,i] <- rnorm(n = length(x))
     idx_na2 <- sample(x=1:length(x),size = length(x)/2)
     my_data[idx_na2,i] <- NA

}

#imputation
est <- mice(my_data)

data2 <- complete(est)

str(data2[,1:3])
```

Places that I have looked for answers:

- help document ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf))
- google of course...
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99334/fast-missing-data-imputation-in-r-for-big-data-that-is-more-sophisticated-than-s

Comment: Many missing value imputation methods work by estimating joint distributions on all variables, so they fill in missing values of all columns recursively to better estimate a joint distribution of all values. The imputation is better if you do it on all columns. If you want to drop the imputed values, just save a dataframe of missing values, and you can reset imputed values to missing in columns you want to keep missing: `is.na(dataframe)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be done by modifying the parameter "where" of the mice function. The parameter "where" is equal to a matrix (or dataframe) with the same size as the dataset on which you are carrying out the imputation. By default, the "where" parameter is equal to is.na(data): a matrix with cells equal to "TRUE" when the value is missing in your dataset and equal to "FALSE" otherwise. This means that by default, every missing value in your dataset will be imputed. Now if you want to change this and only impute the values in a specific column (in my example column 2) of your dataset you can do this:

```
# Define arbitrary matrix with TRUE values when data is missing and FALSE otherwise
A <- is.na(data)
# Replace all the other columns which are not the one you want to impute (let say column 2)
A[,-2] <- FALSE 
# Run the mice function
imputed_data <- mice(data, where = A)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `where` argument a faster way might be to **use the `method` argument**. You can set this argument to `""` for the columns/variables you want to skip. Downside is that automatic determination of the method will not work. So:

```
imp <- mice(data,
            method = ifelse(colnames(data) == "your_var", "logreg", ""))
```

But you can get the default method from [the documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/mice/man/mice.html):

> `defaultMethod`
>
> ... By default, the method uses `pmm`, predictive mean matching (numeric data) `logreg`, logistic regression imputation (binary data, factor with 2 levels) `polyreg`, polytomous regression imputation for unordered categorical data (factor > 2 levels) `polr`, proportional odds model for (ordered, > 2 levels).

Comment: Thx for your reply. I tried it on my dataset and got the following error `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Pack' not found`. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't entirely clear to me. Are you saying you wish to only operate on two columns? In that case `mice(my_data[,1:2])` will work. Or you want to use all the data but only fill in missing values for some columns? To do this, I'd just create an indicator matrix along the following lines:

```
isNA <- data.frame(apply(my_data, 2, is.na))
est <- mice(my_data)

mapply(function(x, isna) {
  x[isNA == 1] <- NA
  return(x)
}, <each MI mice return object column-wise>,  isNA)
```

For your final question, "can I use `mice` for rolling data imputation?" I believe the answer is no. But you should double check the documentation.

Comment: I did this first by making a max interations zero "mice" because it built a structure that had relating columns, and methods.  I then set methods for every column but the one of interests to "" and they were not considered.  I could use the matrix to say which columns feed into which variable for imputation.

Comment: @EngrStudent Your comment is completely unclear to me. I literally do not understand it at all... And your OP is still unclear to me