# Imputation of specific columns with mice()

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I would like to use data imputation by using the mice package. My dataset contains the columns "A" to "G", but I only want to impute the values of column C and D.

In this article (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/06/handling-missing-data-with-mice-package-a-simple-approach/) it is explained how to **exclude** variables from being a predictor or being imputed - but I would like to use mice the other way round: I want to specify which variables **ARE imputed** - so only C and D should be imputed.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe keep only columns that needs imputing?

Comment: But I want to use all information of column A to G also after data imputation... Or is this the wrong way of using imputation. As far as I understand I start with my data with column A to G, then use mice and in the end use the "complete" function to append the imputed data. Or does is work to create a temporary copy of my data, drop all columns which I do not want to impute - so C and D remain, and then use the complete function like data <- complete(tempdata)?

Comment: After imputation you still have you original A & G columns, just replace after imputation?

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I want to use Columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G for all my subsequent analyses, but only apply the imputation on columns C + D. In the end I want to keep original data of A, B, E, F, G combined with the inputed values in colums C + D. I asked this question because I think it is easier to define, which columns I want to impute rather than which columns I DO NOT want to impute. Of couse I could exclude columns A, B, E, F, G - but I thought this could be done easier... I hope, I could explain my problem...

Comment: Related post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42161230/680068

Comment: I think you are going against the idea of multiple imputation, by design you want to have multiple datasets with no missing values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**

Just invert the logic: In the methods vector, set every variable that is not one of your variables of interest to `""`:

```r
meth[!names(meth) %in% c("C", "D")] <- ""
```

---

**Example: Only impute `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width`**

```r
data <- mice::ampute(iris, prop = 0.1)$amp
init <- mice(data, maxit = 0)
meth <- init$meth
meth[!names(meth) %in% c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")] <- ""
mice(data, meth = meth)
```

---

**Rationale**

You can supply a vector to the `method` argument of `mice::mice`. This vector should contain the methods that you want to use to impute the variables you want to impute. In the example they first do a dry-run (`init <- mice(data, maxit = 0)`), where the output contains a preset vector for you (`init$method`). For my example, it looks like this:

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
       "pmm"        "pmm"        "pmm"        "pmm"        "pmm"
```

You can avoid variables being imputed by setting the method to `""`. This is one way to exclude variables. As I show with my example, you can invert that logic, thus ending up with only the variables you want to include.